# Как установить vertices, texCoords и Indices для OpenGL

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl, ar

Я новичок в `AR` и `OpenGL` технологиях

Я нашел вот такой пример связки `AR` и `OpenGL`

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java

В примере есть обьяснение того как создать `AR обьект` и добавить его на экран

**Что это означает** - мы создаем (конфигурируем) `AR object` один раз и после того как он был добавлен на экран мы просто в методе `onDrawFrame()` перерисовываем его каждый фрейм (по `vertices tecCoords indices которые единожды были сформированы)

Тип даты вот такой

```
IntBuffer wideIndices = ObjData.getFaceVertexIndices(obj, 3);
FloatBuffer vertices = ObjData.getVertices(obj);
FloatBuffer texCoords = ObjData.getTexCoords(obj, 2);
```

**Теперь, что мне нужно сделать** - нужно сделать `AR video`. Это значит, что мне нужно каждый новый фрейм пересчитывать `vertices tecCoords indices` и отрисовывать их на экране.

У меня есть метод написаный на `C++` который знает как каждый новый фрейм вернуть мне актуальные `indices vertices texCoords` в таком типе

```
List<float[]> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
List<float[]> texCoords = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> realIndices = new ArrayList<>();
```

Как вы видете тут есть не соответствие типов, так как в примере мы работаем с буферами а мой метод знает как вернуть списки.

Я вижу тут 2 возможных решения

1) найти возможность конвертировать `List` в `Buffer` (но сомневаюсь, что это подойдет...)

2) Найти позможность передать `OpenGL` как то свои данные в том типе который у меня есть

Так как впринципе это тот набор данных который и нужен `OpenGL` для того, чтоб построить `AR object`

Любые идеи приветствуются

Comment: почему Вы решили что надо пересчитывать все каждом кадре?

Comment: это необходимо в случае когда сам объект поменялся, но не его местоположение

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну так сам обьект и меняется... Как раз местоположение остается тем же(в нашем случае), а сам обьект менятеся...

Comment: Не понятно что такое AR video в таком случае

Comment: @StrangerintheQ насколько я понимаю видео это когда на каждом новом фрейме мы отрисовываем новый кард(в нешем случае новый обьект). Допустим первый фрейм есть обьект (человек у которого опущены 2 руки) на следующих фреймах руки поднимаются от фрема к фрейму и когда это все работает на скорости 30 кадров в сек вот и получается видео...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А вы имеете ввиду, что можно сделать тоже самое, но типо создать обьект и не перерисовывать сам обьект, а просто (в данном примере) менять ему положение рук? Но это типо анимация?

Comment: не видя то что Вы там себе напридумывали, без подробного описания не было понятно что у Вас там объекты, которые меняют форму. Это могло быть совершенно иначе, допустим мы просто с разных сторон смотрим на статический объект

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я не совесем понял, что вы имели ввиду... Я наверное, что то не правильно понимаю... Но я вижу это так создаем модель одного образа отрисовываем, следующий кадр создаем модель другого образа и отрисовываем ее... нет?